# Should we rely on software given its $P(\text{Correct})=0.98$ or discard it and DIY

Tags: probability

Assume there's a software developed by an insurance company. It's purpose is to distinguish between fraudulent customers’ insurance claims from those that are honest. Having experimenting with the software on 1000 recent claims, the company finds that

- There were 15 cases of fraud, and the software correctly predicted 10 of these.
- Of the remaining 985 (honest) claims, the software incorrectly predicted that 15 were fraudulent.

What is the probability of the software correctly identifying whether a claim is or is not fraudulent?

Before I started, I wrote all the possible probabilities beforehand for each of the 2 given cases.

**Case 1** whereby number of fraud claims is 15:

- $P(\text{software predicted correctly})=\frac{2}{3}$
- $P(\text{software predicted incorrectly})=\frac{1}{3}$

**Case 2** whereby number of honest claims = 985:

- $P(\text{software predicted correctly as honest})=\frac{194}{197}$
- $P(\text{software predicted incorrectly as honest})=\frac{3}{197}$

**Overall probability** (where $N=1000$):

- $P(\text{fraud})=\frac{3}{200}$
- $P(\text{honest})=\frac{197}{200}$

Additional probabilities:

- $P(\text{Software predicted claim as fraud regardless of it being correct/incorrect}=\frac{1}{40}$
- $P(\text{Software predicted claim as honest regardless of it being correct/incorrect}=\frac{39}{40}$

I know immediately that the question is asking me to use the method as such:

$$
P(\text{fraudulent}|\text{predicted-fraudelent})+P(\text{honest}|\text{predicted-honest})
$$

**Iteration 1:**

After receiving some useful feedbacks from the answer below, 98% seems to be the answer. Given the high probability of the software actually working, should the company continue using the software or just dismiss it completely?

What would the probability of the company being able to identify whether or not a claim is fraudulent?

Comment: Your new questions are not mathematical and do not belong to Math SE, but you can consider asking them at another SE site. In any case, no good company will act based on software that can be wrong. And it is usually preferable to have a software that has few false negatives and then go through the positives one by one to exclude the false positives, rather than to care about the overall error rate. The same considerations arise in medical methods for diagnosing some illnesses.

Comment: If that's the case, which SE site would be more suitable for this kind of question? @user21820

Comment: It depends on your purpose of asking this question I guess. It is either a moral question, in which case my comment is my personal answer, or a question of what is 'best' for the company, in which case it depends on what the company considers 'good' in the first place. In case it isn't clear I'm referring to your question of "should the company continue using the software or just dismiss it completely?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For brevity let F = flagged as as dishonest, N = not flagged, H = honest, D = Dishonest. You can make a Venn Diagram with four
regions FD, FH, ND, NH.

Their probabilities are $P(FD) = 10/1000,$ $PF(FH) = 15/1000,$ $P(ND) = 5/1000,$ and $P(NH) = 970/1000.$ These four disjoint, unconditional probabilities add to 1, as they should.

There are two disjoint correct decisions: FD and NH. The probability of their union is
$$P(FD \cup NH) = P(FD) + F(NH) = (10 + 970)/1000 = 980/1000 = .980 = 98\%.$$

This is the requested proportion of time the software leads to the correct decision.

Note:

1. At first glance, this may seem to be a problem about conditional probabilities, and perhaps Bayes' Theorem. There may be a more complicated way of looking at it to give the correct answer via this point of view. However, I think a better title for this question would be "Adding two disjoint probabilities."
2. Other probabilities might be of interest. For example, $P(D|F) = P(DF)/P(F) = 10/25 = 40\%,$ which is not nearly as high as the probability above. Also, the proportion of false alarms among flagged claims is disturbingly large $P(H|F) = P(FH)/F(F) = 15/25 = 60\%.$ Finally, $P(H|N) = 790/975 = 99.5\%$ is the probability of making a correct decision given an honest claim.

Comment: Notice that the notation in the answer from @GrahamKemp, which appeared while I was typing mine, uses different notation. My P(D|F) and his P(F|D) both mean P(dishonest/fraudulent claim | flagged/detected by software).

Comment: I got another answer which is 40% if I were to use the alternative method given by another user here. Would you agree with the solution? @BruceTrumbo

Comment: As explained in my previous note the 40% answer from @GrahamKemp is equivalent to my _conditional_ probability P(D|F) = P(Dishonest|Flagged by computer) = 40%.  I understood the question to be what percentage of the time the computer will give the right result _overall_ (unconditionally). In my notation, P(Correct identification) = P(Flagged and correct) + P(Not flagged and correct) = P(F)P(D|F) + P(N)P(H|N) = (25/1000)(.40) + (975/1000)(..995)  = .98. In essence, I think the other answer is for only 'half' of you problem. Not to mention, more complicated than necessary.

Comment: I understand your explanation now. So, let's presume that the company decided not to use the software & simply assumes that all claims are honest. If that's the case, I suppose the probability that the company correctly identifies whether or not a claim is fraudulent would be much lower? @BruceTrumbo

Comment: I'll leave speculations about the rationality of corporate behavior to you. Especially if the dishonest claim rate were high, they'd need some criterion for identifying these. One could certainly hope for a method with better 'sensitivity' and 'specificity' than limited data indicate for this computer program.

Answer (score 3):

No, the method is Bayes' Rule and the Law of Total Probability.

Let $F$ be the event of fraud, and $D$ be the event of detection by the software.

We are given

- $\mathsf P(D\mid F) = \tfrac 2 3$
- $\mathsf P(D\mid \neg F) = \tfrac {15}{985}$
- $\mathsf P(F) = \tfrac {3}{200}$
- $\mathsf P(\neg F) = \tfrac {197}{200}$

We wish to find; $\mathsf P(F\mid D)$

We can use: $\;\mathsf P(F\mid D) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(D\mid F)\mathsf P(F)}{\mathsf P(D\mid F)\mathsf P(F)+\mathsf P(D\mid \neg F)\mathsf P(\neg F)}$

Alternatively, you can simply note that of the $10+15$ detections in the sample, only $10$ were actual fraud, so the (conditional) probability of being fraud given detection is: $10/25$ or $0.40$.

---

Now, for the other half of the problem, do the same for not-fraud given no-detection. That is, find: $\;\mathsf P(\neg F\mid \neg D)\;$ .

---

Then $P(\text{Correct}) = \mathsf P(F\mid D)\mathsf P(D)+\mathsf P(\neg F\mid \neg D)\mathsf P(\neg D)$

(Or find the easier way to calculate that from the given numbers.)

Comment: Yes. @iterance .  Alternatively, you can simply note that of the $10+15$ detections in the sample, only $10$ were actual fraud, so the (conditional) probability of being fraud given detection is: $10/25$ or $0.40$.

Answer (score 2):

> - There were 15 cases of fraud, and the software correctly predicted 10 of these.
> - Of the remaining 985 (honest) claims, the software incorrectly predicted that 15 were fraudulent.

Going back to basics, we tabulate these results:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
 & D & \neg D
\\ \hline
F & \color{blue}{10} & \color{red}{5} & 15
\\
\neg F & \color{red}{15} & \color{blue}{970} & 985
\\ \hline
 & 25 & 975 & 1000
\end{array}$$

So of the $1000$ claims, $980$ we correctly assessed by the software. $$\mathsf P\big((F\cap D)\cup (\neg F\cap\neg D)\big) = \frac{980}{1000}$$

Similarly: $\mathsf P(F\mid D) = 10/25, \mathsf P(\neg F\mid \neg D)=970/975$ *et cetera*.

Comment: This explanation clears up my mind now. I'm just curious now, assume that the software works 98% of the time but the company dismisses it entirely, does this mean that probability of the company being able to detect frauds correctly be lower?